# Will App Store Connect Beta App Review overwrite/cancel my current review process for production release?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am currently in the process of deploying a new iOS app. I have my app in review for release to the app store. It initially got rejected so I've corrected the issue, replied to the reviewer, and am now waiting for the review to continue.

I am also looking to set up external testing with the same app. I know that when you add an app to an external testing group for the first time, it must go through Beta App Review.

My question is, if I submit my app for Beta App Review while the production App Review is in process, will the Beta App Review cancel/overwrite the prod review? Will I need to restart the review process for the app store?

Comment: No.  Testflight/beta review is separate to App Store review

Comment: If you are concerned, you can minimize risk by making two builds with different version numbers, and sending one for TF and one for release approval.

Answer (score 0):

> will the Beta App Review cancel/overwrite the prod review?

NO